# Edge is only printing the first page of content and removing Bootstrap fixes it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, bootstrap-4

Ran into an issue where in every other browser the printing was fine, but for Edge it is only printing the first page of a multi-page document.

Thought it was an issue with `[react-to-print][1]`, but I tested it using their project and it printed multiple pages of content fine in Edge. Then I started disabling parts of my CSS, one-at-a-time, until all of my CSS was removed. Issue still persists.

Then I removed the `bootstrap.css` and the issue went away. Added back all of my custom CSS and it worked fine (just looks awful without `bootstrap.css`).

So apparently there is something about Bootstrap 4 that Edge isn't liking. I'm just not sure what attributes could be causing it that I need to override. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, isolated the cause of the issue to this section in the `bootstrap.css`.

```
.table-responsive {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto; /* This is what was causing it */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```

The printing issue is affecting a responsive table. I just commented out the:

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

And now it works properly.

I did try to override it with `!important` using all the acceptable values so I didn't have to modify the `bootstrap.css`:

```
visible | hidden | clip | scroll | auto
```

None of them did anything of value.

Answer (score 1):

@sockpuppet's fix will work for the IE/Edge printing, but it defeats the purpose of the responsive table (allowing the table to scroll horizontally when on a mobile device).

I originally tried adding this after the first `table-responsive` declaration:

```
@media print {
    .table-responsive {
        overflow-x: initial !important;
    }
}
```

This has the desired effect in Edge, and has the added advantage of something you can add outside of the core bootstrap css/scss. However, it doesn't work in IE11. So instead I just wrapped the `.table-responsive` class in screen media. eg

```
@media screen {
    .table-responsive {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    }
}
```

And this worked for both Edge and IE, because the `overflow-x: auto` is only ever needed on a mobile screen. It can be safely ignored when printing. The downside to this is that it needs to be added to the core bootstrap files. I don't know how to force the media on something in the core, from something outside of the core. It isn't additive and it doesn't override. It is this weird modifier.